# O Ajax não está atualizando o texto(.txt)

Tags: ajax

Fiz a conexão ajax(copiei e colei mesmo) pra introduzir na div um texto em .txt então, alterei o texto e salvei, porém continua mostrando o texto antes da modificação

```
<script>
    function corpo(titulo, texto) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = titulo;
            document.getElementById("corpo").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", texto, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Certificou-se se a resposta HTTP possui o texto atualizado ou o antigo? Se possuir o antigo, o problema não é no JS e a pergunta será impossível de responder.

Comment: sim, é o atualizado que ta no mesmo e com o mesmo nome(não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas, eu abri o mesmo arquivo  que estava funcionando e modifiquei salvando depois, excluindo o antigo e colocando o novo imagino eu e..e) se estiver errado, dsclpa :b sou meio burro memo

Comment: Analise a requisição através das ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador.

Comment: Como vc salvou esse texto alterado?

Comment: basicamente to salvando no editor q o próprio site tem. não entendi o que o Anderson falou, então tirei um print. O site é um daqueles subdomínio free e tals, tirei print e se quiser tem o site: https://prntscr.com/libg1i http://estudos.epizy.com/

Comment: Esse seu código nada mais faz do que puxar o conteúdo de um arquivo .txt. Se vc quiser salvar algo, teria que usar um código backend (ex. PHP) para reescrever o arquivo .txt.

Comment: sim, mas eu modifiquei o próprio txt pra alterar o conteúdo do html tipo, eu modifiquei o txt mas é como se eu n tivesse mudado

Comment: https://prntscr.com/lic93o aqui mostra o que ta salvo, e o que aparece(selecionado)